# Iterate through named vector using list

Tags: r, vector

I have two vectors,

```r
v <- (TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
named.v <- (TRUE = "#FF0000FF", FALSE="#00FF00FF", NA="0000FFFF")
```

I am trying to get the color associated to the values in V.

I have tried doing this

```r
named.v[v]
```

But all this does is returns

```
        TRUE       FALSE        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA> 
"#FF0000FF" "#00FF00FF" "#0000FFFF"          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

I'm really stuck and can't figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to match with a character set instead of the logical.  Here, the `names` of 'named.v' is `character` class (though there is inconsistencies in the example created - in general it is the case)

```
named.v[as.character(v)]
#      TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
#"#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF"
```

---

Now, let's look at the issue in the OP's code, 'v' being `logical`, TRUEs implying should select that value, But, the 'named.v' is of length 3, while the logical vector is length 10, so after the first 3 is selected from 'named.v', there is nothing left, so it is missing and `NA` represents missing value

#### data

```
v <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
named.v <- c(`TRUE` = "#FF0000FF", `FALSE`="#00FF00FF", `NA`="0000FFFF")
```

Comment: My goodness. Thank you so much, this has been breaking my head. Still learning the ropes of R, as I'm used to Python usually.